# Textfields is hiding by the Keypad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, iphone-keypad

I have made an app with a Registration form. When the Textfield in this form is selected it gets hidden by the soft keyboard. If i leave it as it is user can't see what he is entering while typing.

Comment: I think you wants to move your textfield to up when editing.. I am right or wrong ...

Comment: @Rajeev u want to move up & down the textfield when click or touch the textfields

Comment: that is only a generic problem of a badly designed view-layer.

Comment: You should give us some more info in order to better help you. First, do you have all those textfields on a ScrollView? If yes, do you have the delegate set for textfields? And yes, show us the code you've tried so faR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the old method ,but working fine for each time

in your .h file

```
@interface signupViewController : UIViewController
{
CGFloat animatedDistance;
 }
```

.m file

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect textFieldRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator =
midline - viewRect.origin.y
- MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator =
(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
* viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
if (heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction = 0.0;
}
else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}


animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: not working @anbu karthik

Comment: what the result u need

Comment: textfield should move up when keyborad present

Comment: it working fine, I used more than 8 projects, k here what the problem u meet

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be helpfull..

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];}

-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
{
    int movementDistance = -100; // tweak as needed
    float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed
    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: if I use the 20 textfield, it working fine for each textfield, why I ask this ? I tried ur answer it scroll up for each textfield when textfield are shown in the normal time also

Comment: U need to implement if/else condition for that....

Comment: i tried it @joge but not working

Comment: @Rajeevleader.. have set textfield delegate or not ... Please implement this if not yet implemented delegate ..   "yourTxtField.delegate = self;"